# C# Foreach usercontrols I added to a page

Tags: c#

I've got this code:

```
    protected void ddlTemplate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Template t = new Template();
    t.LoadById(Convert.ToInt32(ddlTemplate.SelectedItem.Value));
    foreach (Widget w in t.TemplateWidgets)
    {
        UserControls_Widget ucWidget = (UserControls_Widget)LoadControl("~/UserControls/ucWidget.ascx");
        ucWidget.WidgetTitle = w.Name;
        ucWidget.Parameters = w.Parameters;
        pnlWidgets.Controls.Add(ucWidget);
    }

}
protected void lnkSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (Control cc in pnlWidgets.Controls)
    {

    }
}
```

Basically I'd like to foreach the Widgets I added to the page in the ddlTemplate_SelectedIndexChanged event. So the question is how do I get the UserControls I added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your usercontrols to a `List<UserControls_Widget>` and loop through it to instead of looping through all the controls on the page.

Comment: Yeah will have to save to a session between events. Will do this me things.

Comment: Yes that is what I do, if it is postback, load from session, if it's not, save to session.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
foreach(Control cc in pnlWidgets.Controls)
{
    UserControls_Widget widget = cc as UserControls_Widget;
    if (widget == null)
        continue;
    // Do stuff with widget
}
```

Is that the kind of thing you are looking for?

Comment: Nope. If widget is null then continue to the next iteration of the loop. All other paths operate for when widget references something.